# Mamp many httpd

Tags: apache

im running MAMP PRO 4.5 and Apache 2.4.33 and i have a issues on Macosx Activity Monitor, there is a lot of HTTPD operations started (like 90) !

I tryed to edit httpd.conf by File > Edit Template > Apache > httpd.conf

I add the following :

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
  StartServers    5
  MinSpareServers 5
  MaxSpareServers 15
  <IfVersion >= 2.4>
    MaxRequestWorkers       30
    MaxConnectionsPerChild  5000
  </IfVersion>
  <IfVersion < 2.3 >
    MaxClients              30
    MaxRequestsPerChild     5000
  </IfVersion>
</IfModule>
```

I found it here (https://community.bitnami.com/t/multiple-sleeping-mysqld-and-httpd-processes-using-up-available-ram/29171/2)

But i really dont't know what i'm doing and why it don't work ...

Can you help me ?